# Does Silverlight 5 support Dolby Digital (AC-3) 5.1 surround sound playback?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0, codec, smooth-streaming

Does playing video with Silverlight 5 support the playback of Dolby Digital (AC-3) 5.1 surround sound, or will it always downmix the channels to stereo?

I'm streaming a [Smooth Streaming](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/smoothstreaming/) video, but the Silverlight [Smooth Streaming Sample Player](http://smf.codeplex.com/releases/view/88970) doesn't seem to support Dolby audio playback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No with default players.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#delivery_method_containers_and_codecs

Quote:

```
(For WMA audio, the only one mentioning surround sound)
Multichannel (5.1 and 7.1 surround) audio content is automatically mixed down to stereo.
```

---

And for Smooth Streaming:

http://www.iis.net/learn/media/smooth-streaming/smooth-streaming-client-readme

Not many details here, supported audio codec is AAC.

---

See also here:

http://www.iis.net/learn/media/smooth-streaming/smooth-streaming-primer#create_piff

Supported codecs are AAC and WMA/WMA Pro.